# git fetch/pull keeps updating branch

Tags: git, git-fetch

Every time I do a git fetch/pull I am getting and update that a new branch has been downloaded. I am certain that the branch isn't being updated on the server side in the interim.

What could be causing this?

The server is a gitlab instance

See below: (edited for brevity and privacy)

```
> git pull
From <remote_server>
 * [new branch]      branch_name -> origin/branch_name
Already up-to-date.

> git pull
From <remote_server>
 * [new branch]      branch_name -> origin/branch_name
Already up-to-date.

> git fetch
From <remote_server>
 * [new branch]      branch_name -> origin/branch_name

> git br -rd origin/branch_name
Deleted remote-tracking branch origin/branch_name (was 2cce655).

> git fetch
From <remote_server>
 * [new branch]      branch_name -> origin/branch_name

> git fetch
From <remote_server>
 * [new branch]      branch_name -> origin/branch_name


> git --version
git version 2.10.0.windows.1


> git pull origin branch_name
From <remote_server>
 * branch            remote_branch -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      remote_branch -> origin/remote_branch
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.

> git pull origin branch_name
From <remote_server>
 * branch            remote_branch -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      remote_branch -> origin/remote_branch
Already up-to-date.

> git pull origin branch_name
From <remote_server>
 * branch            remote_branch -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]      remote_branch -> origin/remote_branch
Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: Where are you fetching from?

Comment: What does `git pull origin remote_branch` say ?

Comment: git pull returns exactly the same results, well, except that it says "Already up-to-date"

Comment: I am fetching from a company internal gitlab server, hence the modification of origin's details

Comment: The "(curated for brevity and privacy)" has, I think, knocked out a key clue. Use `git branch -r` to list your remote-tracking branches. Is one of them similar to the one that keeps getting "created", except for upper/lower-case mix? And, are you on a Mac or Windows system with a case-folding file system so that file `Foo` can be opened by the name `foo`? (Ah, I see `.windows` in the Git version, which answers the second part.)

Comment: @torek excellent spot. I am indeed on windows. When I execute `git branch -r` as you suggest, I do indeed get a branch with the same name but with one letter different. Local remote tracking branch has lower case in it when the remote one doesn't. I think another user must have created a duplicate of the branch with the case change in one of the letters and deleted the original. Now, if I delete the remote tracking branch, when I git pull, I am still left with the incorrect branch name. Is something being cached?

Comment: Yes, so it's the case-folding problem. There are two places Git keeps branch names: `.git/packed-refs` (a flat file) and `.git/refs/` (a tree of OS handled directories and filenames). The flat file is always case-sensitive and the OS-handled tree depends on the OS, so it winds up being case-*in*sensitive, hence the problem. If you delete the "wrong case" one you should be OK (but check your .git/config file for `merge =` names as well!). Or, convince the upstream to go back to all-lower-case, which is probably the best solution all around :-)

Comment: Hi @torek, if you place your comment as an answer, I'll mark this as answered. I tried deleting the branch in the mechanism you suggested but it doesn't seem to have resolved it. That is, git seems to have sub categorized the branches delimited by a "/". We prepend branches with "feature" for example and the problematic branch is called "Feature". This branch then gets categorized within feature as you suggest which seems to be causing the problem

Comment: Hm, does that mean you have both `feature/foo` and `Feature/bar`? That's definitely problematic and you will definitely have to fix the upstream to be consistent.

Comment: Yes we have both of those. Feature/bar is only one case though. If this is the root of the problem, by all means place this as an answer. I don't to claim credit by answering it myself